# isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications always returns no

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios8, apple-push-notifications

I got the pop up, i have accepted, i see it in the notifications and it is turned on but this code always returns no and i cant seem to find out why

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

BOOL enabled;

// Try to use the newer isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications otherwise use the enabledRemoteNotificationTypes.
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
{

    enabled = [application isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    UIRemoteNotificationType types = [application enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
    enabled = types & UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert;

}
if  (enabled){
    NSLog(@"is registered");
}else{
     NSLog(@"is not registered");
}
```

Comment: When you register for notifications is `UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert` one of the types you register for?

Answer (score 11):

I think what makes it happen might be:

1. isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications will always return NO in
   simulators.
2. registerForRemoteNotifications fails.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same problem, this worked for me.

```
BOOL enabled = NO;
UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [SharedApplication currentUserNotificationSettings];
enabled = notificationSettings.types < 4;
```

Comment: #define SharedApplication                   [UIApplication sharedApplication]

Comment: This has a huge chance of actually lying to you. If you haven't registered for remote notifications you could still have the notification settings setup so this could return true when in fact it is false. You should be relying on the returned value in `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` and if this is returning `NO` this means something has gone wrong with your registration for remote notifications.

Comment: `notificationSettings.types > 0` is a better approach. 7 means banner, sound and alert are enabled, but it will return false because of 7 > 4

Answer (score 1):

As per the Apple documentation `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` will return `NO` if registration has not occurred, has failed, or has been denied by the user. `YES` will be returned if the app has registered for remote notifications and has received is device token. So in answer to your question **NO** it will not always return `no` it will also return `yes` if a your app has registered for remote notifications and it has received it device token.

[Checkout the Apple Documentation for a better description](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)

> **Return Value**
>
> `YES` if the app is registered for remote notifications and received its device token or `NO` if registration has not occurred, has failed, or has been denied by the user.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This method reflects only the successful completion of the remote registration process that begins when you call the `registerForRemoteNotifications` method. This method does not reflect whether remote notifications are actually available due to connectivity issues. The value returned by this method takes into account the user’s preferences for receiving remote notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simulator will always return `no`, try running your code on a real device and see if the behavior continues

Answer (score 0):

After iOS10 and to make it work both on the simulator and on a real device you should use something like this:

```
[[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:^(UNNotificationSettings * _Nonnull settings) {
     if (settings.alertStyle == UNAlertStyleNone)
         NSLog(@“ACCESS DENIED!”);
     else
         NSLog(@“ACCESS GRANTED!”);
 }];
```

If you are NOT planning to test on the simulator you may use the code below (unfortunately this will always return NO on the simulator):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications];
```

Do NOT use the code below if you are planning to compile for iOS 10 or iOS11 because it has been deprecated on iOS10:

```
[SharedApplication currentUserNotificationSettings];
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `[UIApplication sharedApplication].isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` is always NO when capability Background Modes > Remote notifications hasn't been turned on.